# Python Instance Not created

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, undefined

```
from collections import defaultdict 

class Graph: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.graph = defaultdict(list) 
        
    def addEdge(self,u,v): 
        self.graph[u].append(v) 

g = Graph() 
g.addEdge(0, 1) 
g.addEdge(0, 2) 
g.addEdge(1, 2) 
g.addEdge(2, 0) 
g.addEdge(2, 3) 
g.addEdge(3, 3) 

print (graph)
```

**when i run it it says "name graph not defined"** whats the problem here? i tried changing in different ways but error still remains

Comment: `print (graph)` Did you mean `print (g.graph)` ?

Comment: You have a `print(graph)` while the variable `graph` is not defined. You have to `print(g)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) element outside the class, so you need to point it using the object created that contain the class, essentially change in your code `print(graph)` with `print(g.graph)`.

```
from collections import defaultdict 

class Graph: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.graph = defaultdict(list) 
        
    def addEdge(self,u,v): 
        self.graph[u].append(v) 

g = Graph() 
g.addEdge(0, 1) 
g.addEdge(0, 2) 
g.addEdge(1, 2) 
g.addEdge(2, 0) 
g.addEdge(2, 3) 
g.addEdge(3, 3) 

print (g.graph)
```

Comment: @R.K if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.